# Is null and is not null operator are not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

i'am using Kendo UI and in which i have data filter where many more filter operator are available  there for example 'is greater than ' 'is less than ' 'is greater then or equal ' 'null' and is not null' 
all are working but when i select the 'null ' and is not null' these two operator are throwing exception

exception is "This operator is not yet supported for this Grid" 
if anyone has any idea of it please make me clear !

thank in advance :)

Comment: please add some code and detail to make your question clear.

Comment: Can you add some code to your question? so it would be easy to answer.

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer of my question i have attached a peace of code bellow in which all the filters are working properly but when i select the 'is null' and 'is not null' option exception throw . could you help me out .......

Comment: guys can anyone help me out on this ?

Answer (score 0):

public static string BuildWhereClause(int index, string logic, GridFilter filter, System.Collections.ArrayList parameters)
        {

```
        var entityType = (typeof(T));
        PropertyInfo property;
        if (filter.Field.Contains("."))
            property = GetNestedProp<T>(filter.Field);
        else
            property = entityType.GetProperty(filter.Field, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public |
                BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        property = entityType.GetRuntimeProperty(filter.Field);
        var parameterIndex = parameters.Count;
        switch (filter.Operator.ToLower())
        {
            case "eq":
            case "neq":
            case "gte":
            case "gt":
            case "lte":
            case "lt":
            case "isnull":
            case "isnotnull":
                if (property != null)
                {


                    if (typeof(DateTime).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
                    {
                        //if(filter.Operator.ToLower()== "isnull") // check to the all insted of giving values to the  case 

                        parameters.Add(DateTime.Parse(filter.Value).Date);

                        return string.Format("EntityFunctions.TruncateTime({0}){1}@{2}", filter.Field, ToLinqOperator(filter.Operator), index);
                    }
                    if (typeof(DateTime?).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
                    {
                        parameters.Add(DateTime.Parse(filter.Value).Date);
                        return string.Format("EntityFunctions.TruncateTime({0}){1}@{2}", filter.Field, ToLinqOperator(filter.Operator), index);
                    }
                    if (typeof(int).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
                    {
                        parameters.Add(int.Parse(filter.Value));
                        return string.Format("{0}{1}@{2}", filter.Field, ToLinqOperator(filter.Operator), index);
                    }
                    if (typeof(int?).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
                    {
                        parameters.Add(int.Parse(filter.Value));
                        return string.Format("{0}{1}@{2}", filter.Field, ToLinqOperator(filter.Operator), index);
                    }
                    if (typeof(Decimal?).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
                    {
                        if (filter.Operator.ToLower() == "isnull")
                        {
                           parameters.Add(Boolean.Parse(filter.Value));
                            return string.Format("{0}{1}@{2}", filter.Field, ToLinqOperator(filter.Operator), index);


                        }
                        else
                        {
                            parameters.Add(Decimal.Parse(filter.Value));
                            return string.Format("{0}{1}@{2}", filter.Field, ToLinqOperator(filter.Operator), index);
                        }

                    }
                    if (typeof(Decimal).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
                    {
                        parameters.Add(Decimal.Parse(filter.Value));
                        return string.Format("{0}{1}@{2}", filter.Field, ToLinqOperator(filter.Operator), index);
                    }

                    //if(typeof(Boolean?).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
                    //{
                    //    parameters.Add(Boolean.Parse(filter.Value));
                    //}

                    //if (typeof(Boolean).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
                    //{
                    //    parameters.Add(Decimal.Parse(filter.Value));
                    //}



                }
                parameters.Add(filter.Value);
                return string.Format("{0}{1}@{2}", filter.Field, ToLinqOperator(filter.Operator), index);
            case "startswith": parameters.Add(filter.Value); return string.Format("{0}.StartsWith(" + "@{1})", filter.Field, index);
            case "endswith":
                parameters.Add(filter.Value); return string.Format("{0}.EndsWith(" + "@{1})", filter.Field, index);
            case "contains": parameters.Add(filter.Value); return string.Format("{0}.Contains(" + "@{1})", filter.Field, index);
            default: throw new ArgumentException("This operator is not yet supported for this Grid", filter.Operator);
        }
    }
```